# How to create a listview that follows a path in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I intend to create a custom listview that has the following features:

- Its items' layout follow a "path" rather being placed in a linear
  list
- Its items differ in size as the "path" ends
- It can be scrolled normally as a listview

The path is not visible, it's just a background but the layout should follow that virtual path.

Here is a design concept:

[image: Listview path]

What view should I use? Is this possible with customizing a ListView?

Comment: You may be able to achieve this with a subclass of ListView and then in onDraw apply a transform matrix before drawing.  I haven't tried it - hence a comment and not an answer.

Comment: If you remove the centre line from your figure, then the problem burns down to 1. Left and right aligned Stubs.(Achievable!)  2. Diminishing/Increasing size of the stubs on scroll(Achievable!).